# In Unity, if a component is found in an IF condition, use it immediately

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've seen a shorthand of "if a component was found in the IF condition, use it"

so instead of this

```
SomeScript script = gameObject.GetComponent<SomeScript>();

if (script != null) {
  script.DoSomething();
}
```

I saw some kind of shorthand like this

```
if (SomeScript script = gameObject.GetComponent<SomeScript>()) {
  script.DoSomething();
}
```

Anyone know what I mean? Sorry for not knowing the terminology

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are most likely looking for the (recently added, I think starting from 2019.2 and up) `TryGetComponent`.

From the [unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.TryGetComponent.html):

> Gets the component of the specified type, if it exists.
>
> TryGetComponent will attempt to retrieve the component of the given type. The notable difference compared to GameObject.GetComponent is that this method does not allocate in the Editor when the requested component does not exist.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class TryGetComponentExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        if (TryGetComponent(out HingeJoint hinge))
        {
            hinge.useSpring = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Or using your example

```
if (TryGetComponent(out SomeScript script)) 
{
  script.DoSomething();
}
```

If the component gets found using `TryGetComponent` the reference to the found component will be stored in the [`out` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier), that you can then use inside the `if` block.

If no matching component is found it goes to the `else` section.

Comment: I did not know this existed and I'm delighted that I randomly clicked this question, thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

The [true](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) one liner...

```
gameObject.GetComponent<SomeScript>()?.DoSomething();
```

Comment: This will definitely work very well if you're only planning on only calling a function on it once, however keep in mind that if you want to do more than one thing with the component you'll have to perform the check every time you wish to interact with it, since you don't/can't make a reference to the component with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the method multiple times, then it's better to do it in two calls, first cache it in awake

```
 private someScript script;
 void Awake()
 {
     someScript = GetComponent<SomeScript>();
 }
```

And then when you use it in for example Update:

```
void Update()
{
     if(someScript)
     {
         // Do something with someScript
     }
     // or:
     someScript?.DoSomething();
 }
```

It's highly recommended that you annotate your script with the RequireComponent attribute:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(SomeScript))]
public class MyScriptThatRequiresSomeScript : MonoBehaviour
```

Then the component is automatically added when you add your script to a game object

Comment: Great answer! This answer is only for a one time use but I'm sure other people will find this useful